# inner join with huge dataframes (~2 million columns)

Tags: python, r, pandas, merge, inner-join

I am trying to join two data frames (`df1` and `df2`) based on matching values from one column (called 'Names') that is found in each data frame. I have tried this using R's `inner_join` function as well as Python's pandas `merge` function, and have been able to get both to work successfully on smaller subsets of my data. I think my problem is with the size of my data frames.

My data frames are as follows:

- `df1` has the 'Names' column with 5 additional columns and has ~900 rows.
- `df2` has the 'Names' column with ~2million additional columns and has ~900 rows.

I have tried (in R):

```
df3 <- inner_join(x = df1, y = df2, by = 'Name')
```

I have also tried (in Python where `df1` and `df2` are Pandas data frames):

```
df3 = df1.merge(right = df2, how = 'inner', left_on = 1, right_on = 0)
```

(where the 'Name'  column is at index 1 of df1 and at index 0 of df2)

When I apply the above to my full data frames, it runs for a very long time and eventually crashes.  Additionally, I suspect that the problem may be with the 2 million columns of my `df2`, so I tried sub-setting it (row-wise) into smaller data frames. My plan was to join the small subsets of `df2` with `df1` and then row bind the new data frames together at the end. However, joining even the smaller partitioned `df2`s was unsuccessful.

I would appreciate any suggestions anyone would be able to provide.

Comment: can you say anything about the memory footprints (in MB/GB) of the individual objects and the OS/amount of memory you have available?

Comment: Try using `data.table`.

Comment: Should your columns be rows? Reshaping to long form may simplify things.

Comment: If memory issues are a problem, and you want to use python, you can try using a dask dataframe.  http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html  -

Comment: Is this a 1:1, 1:many many:1 or many:many merge?

Comment: Can you filter out some rows beforehand? That is, `drop` all rows from `df2` where `df2.Names` is not in `df1.Names.unique()`, and vice versa. Would that reduce the dataset size?

Comment: @shadowtalker I am relatively new to R and did not think to use data.table.  It worked very nicely, thank you so much!

Comment: Computer has 256 gb or RAM with 6tb hd and 20 cores xeon 2600v2 processor. We mostly use this computer for sequencing based tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you everyone for your help!  Using data.table as @shadowtalker suggested, sped up the process tremendously.  Just for reference in case anyone is trying to do something similar, df1 was approximately 400 mb and my df2 file was approximately 3gb.

I was able to accomplish the task as follows:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(df1)
df2 <- setDT(df2)
setkey(df1, Name)
setkey(df2, Name)
df3 <- df1[df2, nomatch = 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a really ugly workaround where I break up df2's columns and add them piece by piece. Not sure it will work, but it might be worth a try:

```
# First, I only grab the "Name" column from df2
df3 = df1.merge(right=df2[["Name"]], how="inner", on="Name")  

# Then I save all the column headers (excluding 
# the "Name" column) in a separate list
df2_columns = df2.columns[np.logical_not(df2.columns.isin(["Name"]))]

# This determines how many columns are going to get added each time.
num_cols_per_loop = 1000

# And this just calculates how many times you'll need to go through the loop
# given the number of columns you set to get added each loop
num_loops = int(len(df2_columns)/num_cols_per_loop) + 1

for i in range(num_loops):
    # For each run of the loop, we determine which rows will get added
    this_column_sublist = df2_columns[i*num_cols_per_loop : (i+1)*num_cols_per_loop]

    # You also need to add the "Name" column to make sure 
    # you get the observations in the right order
    this_column_sublist = np.append("Name",this_column_sublist)

    # Finally, merge with just the subset of df2
    df3 = df3.merge(right=df2[this_column_sublist], how="inner", on="Name")
```

Like I said, it's an ugly workaround, but it just might work.